# Right way to retrieve the high-order word through C macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

According to microsoft [HIWORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro retrieves the high-order word from the specified 32-bit value.

The original definition of macro is:

```
#define HIWORD(l)  ((WORD)((((DWORD_PTR)(l)) >> 16) & 0xffff))
```

For example if the passed argument is a `unsigned long` value *0x12345678*, return result is *0x1234*

Rewrite the macro as follows:

```
#define MYHIWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) >> 16))
```

The returned result is the same value *0x1234*

My question:

- When passing same arguments, why both macro return the same result ?
- What is purpose of [AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation (& 0xffff) in first macro ?

Comment: Have you tried them both on a plain (signed) `long` initialized with 0xFEDCBA98, which has the high-order bit set?  A lot depends on what the WORD and DWORD_PTR types are.  They're probably from Microsoft (`<windows.h>` or thereabouts), but I don't know what the 'real' types that they represent are.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in both case (signed or unsigned) long it return 0xFEDC

Comment: OK; then the DWORD_PTR type must be an unsigned type and the masking is not relevant.  If it was a signed type and if the compiler did an 'arithmetic shift right' instead of a 'logical shift right', then the result of shifting 0xFEDCBA98 right 16 places would be 0xFFFFFEDC and the mask would be needed to remove the leading four F's.  You might need to know about attempts to port Windows to DEC Alpha and Intel Itanium to be aware that there might at one time have been platform dependencies behind the type names, even if they are now fixed for Intel IA-32 and x86/64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is purpose of AND operation (& 0xffff) in first macro ?

It's not necessary, as the cast will eliminate the high-order bits.  I guess it's just there to highlight (to the reader) the fact that bits are being removed.

Comment: Does this also mean that macro(without mask at the end) is not compiler-dependent ?

Comment: @boleto: Well it requires `WORD` and `DWORD_PTR` to be typedeffed appropriately.